# How to print the name of sub-directory in python?

Tags: python

I want to get the name of sub-directories in Python,

eg : Folder A hav sub folders `a,b,c,d` ect...

I want to get name of  all the folders inside the folders `a,b,c, ...`

Comment: Have you looked at `os.walk`?

Comment: The dupe I linked you to filters sub-directories out; just invert the test to filter files out instead.

Answer (score -2):

[`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.listdir) should do the trick.

Comment: This'll list regular files and symlinks too; you need to tell the OP how to use that function to list just directories.